# Workflow for using TextMate/Coda with Transmit and Versions

Tags: html, css, workflow, textmate, coda

I use TextMate to do my HTMl,PHP,JS/Other languages and CSSEdit to do my CSS.

I want to integrate TextMate with Transmit better because at the moment I work like this:

TextMate: Edit code
Transmit: Look for folder and drag to online server
Firefox: Refresh page
Rinse, Repeat.

It feels very clunky to me and I do the same with CSSEdit (although CSSEdit's live preview means that I only have to upload once) but I would like to be able to, on save, have Transmit upload the edited document to the relevant place on the server (given that linked browsing is enabled).

Does anyone have a certain workflow that they follow or macros enabled in TextMate to do such tasks as they would certainly make my life a lot easier, Coda is also an option instead of TextMate if needed.

Being able to have Versions/Git-Tower auto commit on save would be great too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend @Adam's solution for the uploading part of your question but why are you using Git and Transmit simultaneously? Why not Git for everything?

My workflow:

- On my machine I keep a Git repository where I do all the work. The working directory is served by MAMP so that I can test my code before commiting anything.
- When I'm satisfied I commit my latest changes until I think the branch I'm working on is stable.
- When I'm ready, I push to the server where a post-commit hook checks out the latest version to what the "pre-prod server".
- When everything has been tested to death, branches merged and so on I check out manually the repository to the "prod server".

No need to use an FTP client at any point, everything is done from the editor (TextMate before, Vim now).

Comment: Sounds all very nice, Do you have shared hosting or a dedicated server? As I am on shared hosting at the minute I am restricted as to what I can do but I plan to move to a MediaTemple hosted server this year anyway, As for your git repositories, do you have any advice on what resources to use to learn Git? Could you detail the process in more detail please?

Comment: @Miles Gray, I typically use a VPS at [Linode](http://goo.gl/xjvD0). It's sort of half way between shared and dedicated and I can install and tweak whatever I need. As for advices, Git is extremely popular these days so there are many tutorials on the web. Here are a few resources : [intro](http://goo.gl/RGcxj), [reference](http://gitref.org/), [tutorial](http://goo.gl/kPwAL), [tutorial on which I based my workflow](http://goo.gl/Ybzik), [similar](http://goo.gl/15fmY), [another one](http://goo.gl/44E1W) and [a nice cheatsheet](http://goo.gl/w8RkR).

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a site in Transmit, and open the local directory that holds your files, you can activate the Textmate Transmit bundle by typing ctrl-shift-f. Then hit either 1 or 2. 1 will upload the current directory, 2 will send the current file.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Transmit's ability to mount FTP servers as volumes and simply edit the files directly on the server. To TextMate the mounted FTP server will appear to be just another volume. Search the help files for Transmit Disk, their name for this feature.